# Error callback when the remote database goes down using the sync setup

Tags: pouchdb

When a request to the remote database (eg. `http://localhost:5984`) fails because the database can not be reached, I would like to show an indicator to the user they are offline.

However, using the following sync-setup, the `error` handler does not get triggered when the connection fails. It only get's triggered if the database connection can not be established when setting up the sync. But if the database goes down later on, it seems like the `error` callback isn't triggered. But I'd also like to get notified for this.

My synchronisation setup:

```
localDb
    .sync(remoteDb, {
        live: true,
        retry: true
    })
    .on('error', function () {
        // I would expect this handler to be called when the connection goes down
    });
```

My question is what callback get's triggered after the initial sync has been setup setup and the database can not be reached later on?

Answer (score 0):

You can [listen to database changes](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#changes). There is an `error` event when an error occurs, which might help you.

Comment: 'the error handler does not get triggered when the connection fails'

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to be that short. I did test it but the error did not trigger the `error` callback. That's not the behaviour I expected, hence my question to the community here. Thanks in advance!